# Word or a phrase for finance sharing in groups?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

Is there a word or a phrase for a financial scenario where all participants put money in one pile and then the organizer uses that money to buy whatever the group agreed upon (eg. airplane tickets, concert tickets, birthday gift...)?

Some examples:

1. *Let's _____, it'll be much more efficient.*
2. *One benefit of _____ is getting a discount for a larger purchase.*
3. *Skyler plans to organize _____ for our trip to London.*

Let me make an analogy with carpooling:

1. *Let's carpool, it'll be much more efficient.*
2. *One benefit of carpooling is bypassing the traffic by using the carpool lane.*
3. *Skyler plans to carpool for the next three months.*

Comment: ***pool our funds***. Or *money* or *cash* or whatever instead of funds. *Pool* is the key word.

Comment: Note that the way you've structured your examples is likely to generate three different forms of the word, i.e. verb, present participle, noun phrase. For example, **share**: "Let's *share*", "One benefit of *sharing*", "Skyler plans to organise *shared expenses*".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've almost given the answer yourself with "carpooling": a [*pool*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pool) is

> 3: an aggregation of the interests or property of different persons made to further a joint undertaking by subjecting them to the same control and a common liability

<sub>(source: Merriam-Webster)</sub>

Since pool has some other meanings as well (a swimming pool, a billiard game) you might need to specify *what* you're pooling to avoid ambiguation.

A related concept is [*group buying*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_buying) or *collective buying*, but there you usually don't know the other participants; there is usually some third party service trying to make the group as large as possible. (I assume you do know the other participants, given the examples you mention.) It would fit perfectly in sentence 2 though.